# FireCCI51 on Google Earth Engine: burnt area as shapefiles

Tags: google-earth-engine, vectorization

How can I export my results as shapefiles (polygons) from the burnt area results (raster)?

I intend to export these shapefiles to ArcGIS for further anlysis on a specific national scale.

Link to example code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples:Datasets/ESA_CCI_FireCCI_5_1

Comment: What have you tried so far to vectorize this raster? Without any examples or possible solutions from your side, this questions risks being closed.

Comment: Have you tried reduceToVectors function in EE. It will convert it to feature collection then you can export it to drive ?